# Based on C/S structure，how to query history records with some conditions quickly?

Tags: c#, .net

Our project is C/S structure. In the client, we have some query pages. About how to query datas quickly, there are 2 thoughts:

1) The [Service] part do the query everytime. When the conditions are changed, the client sends the new conditions to the service, the service will do the query to get new datas, then return them to the client.

2) The [Service] part do the query just in the first time. The [Client] part can save the searched data in the client. In the next query, if the data has been in the client, the [client] do the query, if not the [service] do the query and update the [client] datas.

Now, can you tell me, in the real project , which one is used frequently? Thank you very much.

Comment: what's `client` in your question? and how is it do the query?

Comment: A [WPF] window's client. The query is occured in the query page. For example, click the [Search] button ,the results will be shown in the gridview.

Comment: is your `client` and `service` under same project/system?

Comment: No, the Client is [WPF] client in the Windows OS.  the Service is developed by C++，which run in the Unix/Linix OS.DataBase is Oracle. And the communication between Client and Service is the Socket connection which used TCP.